# How to highlight the button when the mouse pointer moves over it?

Tags: delphi

I need to highlight the button when the mouse pointer moves over it. Currently I am using TbitButton.

Comment: What kind of a highlighting do you want

Comment: This happens for free. Are you by any chance using a very dated version of Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think You are using Delphi 7 (from your previous posts)

Just drag and drop XPManifest component from win32 tab in your tool pallet.Run your app now

or create a XML file with

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
        processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

and save it as yourexename.exe.Manifest and save it on the same directory your exe is stored.

//replace "yourexename" with your application name

Comment: I think that the `TBitBtn` is not drawn by Windows, but using code in the VCL. In modern versions of Delphi, the `TBitBtn` has support for visual themes (if themes are enabled, it is drawn using the theme services; if not, it is drawn using plain rectangles). I am not sure if this behaviour is present in the Delphi 7 `TBitBtn`. If not, the OP needs to use an ordinary `TButton` instead.

Comment: Good. Then we know that the `TBitBtn` was changed from D6 to D7.